# Apply different CSS to each element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom

I'm trying to loop through `li` elements of a parent `ul` with a specific class and assign a variable margin to each of them, depending on the height of the previous element in the loop:

```js
$(function() {
  var staticOffset = 66;
  var previousHeight = null; // initialization
  $(".timeline-tidy li").each(function() {
    if (previousHeight) { // exclude the first element
      var heightOffset = previousHeight - staticOffset;
      this.css('margin-top', heightOffset * -1); // negative margin
    }
    previousHeight = this.height();
  });
});
```

I'm obviously doing something wrong though. Could you help me out?

Comment: Can you show some HTML as well so we can test this?

Comment: `this.height()`  What about opening your console???

Comment: Try changing every `this` by `$(this)` as you are using jQuery

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this question.  Whoever down-voted this shouldn't be trying to answer questions on this site in the first place.  It's a simple fix for a simple misunderstanding.  Smh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not referencing `this` correctly in the function.  You need to wrap it with `$()` to turn it into a jQuery object, both to set css and get the height...

```
$(function() {
  var staticOffset = 66;
  var previousHeight = null; // initialization
  $(".timeline-tidy li").each(function() {
    if (previousHeight) { // exclude the first element
      var heightOffset = previousHeight - staticOffset;
      $(this).css('margin-top', heightOffset * -1); // negative margin
    }
    previousHeight = $(this).height();
  });
});
```

However, since you're doing it more than once I'd recommend creating a local reference to it, like this...

```
$(function() {
    var staticOffset = 66;
    var previousHeight = null; // initialization
    $(".timeline-tidy li").each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        if (previousHeight) { // exclude the first element
            var heightOffset = previousHeight - staticOffset;
            $this.css('margin-top', heightOffset * -1); // negative margin
        }
        previousHeight = $this.height();
    });
});
```